# Getting to the right stack for an exception

Tags: c++, windows, windbg

I'm working on an application that has a software watchdog.  If some thread locks up, or is in a wait for more than a minute, the watchdog causes an exception in order to pull down the application and restart it.

So I'm looking at dumpfiles whose faulting stack is pointing at the watchdog thread.  I need to identify the real faulting thread.

I'm looking for general advice and a possible strategy for using windbg to identify the real faulting thread.

Comment: "Fault" has a very specific meaning; it's very likely that the "locked" thread isn't faulting at all. More specifically, deadlocks in general take _two_ threads, so it wouldn't even make sense to identify _the_ offending thread.

Comment: Agreed.  I can't view locks, and I can't see any locked threads.

Comment: Check the stack traces; any deadlocked thread would be blocked inside a "lock" function of some sort - you'd need at least two such threads for a deadlock.

Comment: Yep, checked all that.  Most threads are sleeping on WaitForSingleObject or similar.  The process has an uptime of > 44 days, so I'm thinking its maybe a heap corruption

Comment: WFSO can signal a deadlock. If one thread has locked A and waits for B, while another has B locked and waits for A (cyclic dependency), you already have a deadlock. But you can't see what resources are already locked from just callstacks, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dump files you don't have information you are looking for (cpu usage history), but you can list all threads and examine stack. This will most probably help because the thread that caused the closed  should be blocked in wait or something like that

Comment: yeah, I've looked for a blocked thread.  They all seem normal.  !locks are unavailable too...

Comment: maybe it's something with the watchdog. how do you detect that a thread has blocked ?

Comment: Each thread passes an event handle to the watchdog, and the watchdog resets the timer for each event handle every time the thread checks in.  If a thread doesn't check in for > 1 minute, the watchdog causes the application to crash, suspends all the processes threads, then takes a minidump.  ( Not my design ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Application verifier is good tool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Application verifier slows down the code and provide a lot of commands to analyses the issues.

in general, to find the issues in release mode,

1. generate the pdb for the release build
2. If your release run on your development PC, open visual studio and attached the process (easier way)

otherwise you need to take the dump and apply pdbs and find out..you should archive the pdp files for each release. If you have pdp files then you can easily find the stack trace using debug tool. If you do not have pdp, give a new build and preserve the pdb and get back the minidump from customer (if your customer is flexible).

Comment: Well, I'm looking at crash dump files from a customer (minidumps!), so in this instance, it doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

The watchdog should know which thread didn't respond in time, since it's the one checking. You mention that there is an event for each thread.. perhaps the watchdog thread's stack still has some info on it that can help you deduce which thread was unresponsive?

If not, then just dump all the stack traces with a ~*kc command and see if you can find anything suspicious.

Keep in mind that a dump is a snapshot of the application's state. That means probability-wise, none of the threads should be in functions that don't run frequently or are short-lived.

One trick (for relatively deterministic applications) is to get a few dumps of the application running in a non-hung state. Then you'll know what the stack traces SHOULD look like. When you examine the dump of the hung process, certain threads' stacks should jump out at you.